# Writer file TXT in Memory Internal android

Tags: android, file

I need to write text file in the smartphone internal memory, and then need to copy this .txt file to your computer via the USB cable and accessing his memory (This copy process will make manual, need to locate this file and understand which memory location will be recorded).

I am using the code below, which shows no errors when I run, but I do not know if this recording, and I do not know exactly what directory on your smartphone it should be.

This function is the button to call the function salvarInternalStorage

```
    findViewById(R.id.distance_demo_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override public void onClick(View v) {
     Trilateration tri = new Trilateration(v.getContext());
     try {
       tri.salvarInternalStorage("Trying to Save This text Example");
     } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
     startListBeaconsActivity(DistanceBeaconActivity.class.getName());
   }
});
```

This function is where you should write to the "File.txt" the text passed by parameter.

```
public void salvarInternalStorage(String texto) throws IOException{
            // Use Activity method to create a file in the writeable directory
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("FileTeste.txt", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // Create buffered writer
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
            writer.write(String.valueOf(texto.getBytes()));
            writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Test in Android 6.0 Moto g 3

Comment: This code fellow went down , worked on android 5.1, moto g1, but not android 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

With SAF:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    createFile("text/plain","Arquivo.txt");
}

private static final int WRITE_REQUEST_CODE = 43;

private void createFile(String mimeType, String fileName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);

    // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as
    // a file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones).
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // Create a file with the requested MIME type.
    intent.setType(mimeType);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);
    startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==WRITE_REQUEST_CODE&&resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        alterDocument(data.getData());
}

private void alterDocument(Uri uri) {
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor txt = getContentResolver().
                openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
                new FileOutputStream(txt.getFileDescriptor());
        fileOutputStream.write(("Tentando Gravar Esse Texto Exemplo").getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();
        txt.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or you can use the OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE once to choose a directory and after that you have all permissions to save any file under that directory without ask the user. Something like this:

```
Uri sdCardUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                sdCardUri = data.getData();

                getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(sdCardUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
            createFile();

            break;
    }
}

private void createFile() {
    DocumentFile sdCard=DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this,sdCardUri);
    DocumentFile createFile=sdCard.findFile("teste.txt");
    if (createFile==null)
        createFile=sdCard.createFile("text","teste.txt");
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(createFile.getUri());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        String teste="Isto é um teste";
        outStream.write(teste.getBytes());
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tried to use this code, the site got to write is: /storage/emulated/0/Download
however, this site does not create the folder or file; (, since I authorized all permissions.

Comment: that happens only on 6.0?

Comment: Edited: new approach using saf